# Customize the output style of a view field

Tags: views, entities, theming

I have a view block, where fields are added in the table.
I followed below steps to customize the output fields:

1. Navigate to the edit screen for a view (for example, admin/structure/views/view/MYVIEWNAME/edit).
2. In the Fields section, click a field. The Configure Field dialog box displays.
3. Click Style Settings.
4. Enabled the following options:
           Customize Field HTML
5. Specified the HTML element `<div>` to wrap around the item. and clicked on Create a CSS Class and specified a class name.
6. disabled the Add Default Classes option.
7. Clicked on Apply.

   **The problem is, the specified class name in step no. 5**. got added to the corresponding `<td>` of the view table and not to the selected html element `<div>`

   How to add class name for the specified HTML element `<div>` ?

Comment: I still don't get the question, so you added a div class of "example" in step 5.    So what's the problem?

Comment: I want <td> <div class="test">fieldname</div> </td> for the view field, so i selected HTML element <div> and specified class name 'test' . But once i save and output is  <td class="test"> <div>fieldname</div> </td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, don't use Style Settings. Instead, use Rewrite results.

Click on Replacement patterns, to get the Token of your field.

Then just wrap Token inside div tag.

[image]